# JavaScript return condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, return

Is it possible to have conditions in return in JavaScript?

Like in this case:

```
if
  (A > 0 || B > 0)
    return "A";
  else return "C"
```

As long as A or B is > 0 return the one that is > 0 (so A or B). Is that possible?  Like another condition as return, for example?

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Not exactly in that way, but yes conceptually (and in a very similar way) that can be done. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Not this code, particularly, since this is schematic. I don't know what to 'return' in order for it to only return the true expression (A or B)

Comment: `return true` or `return (A || B)`?

Comment: Thanks, @danh, your link helped a lot! I've achieved what I wanted by using if / else if / else. Great idea!

Comment: @mykaf that doesn't return `A` or `B` whichever is greater than zero. Consider `A = -1`, the return value would be `-1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is similar to what you are trying to do. My function `eval()` takes two parameters `A` and `B`, and checks different conditions to see which is the positive number. I am using the Logical AND `&&` instead of `||` because I want my code to know the value of each parameter in each condition.

```js
function eval(A, B) {
  if (A > 0 && B <= 0) {
    return 'A';
  }
  if (A <= 0 && B > 0) {
    return 'B';
  }
  if (A > 0 && B > 0) return "Both A and B are positive numbers";
}

console.log(eval(2, -5));
console.log(eval(0, 8));
console.log(eval(1, 1));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```js
    return (A > 0 || B > 0) ? "A" : "C"
```

It's a ternary operator. Here you have more information:
[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: ternaries shouldn't be used where another option is available; leave the minification to the minification process

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```js
if(A > 0 || B > 0)
    return A > 0 ? "A" : "B";
else return "C";
```